# Caching large database php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

While trying to display a large database table and making it searchable but I found out it takes a long time to do the search query before the page is done loading.

I am using the phpjabbers search script for presentation/functionality

[MySQL Table Search](https://www.phpjabbers.com/free-mysql-table-search-script/)

Since the database does not really change I wondered if it made more sense to "cache" it in a text file.

The normal search is:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM mydatabsetable";
if ($result = $con->query($sql)) {
  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
?>
  <tr>
     <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['number']; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['city']; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['country']; ?></td>
  </tr>
<?
}
}
?>
```

So I tried changing to:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM mydatabasetable";
if ($result = $con->query($sql)) {
  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  file_put_contents('cache.txt', serialize(json_encode($row)));                        
}
}
?>
```

Unfortunately no file is created (or I just can't find it).

First off: is it a lot quicker to read from text file?
Second: what is wrong with my code to create a "cache file"?

I understand that after this I will have to check timestamp of file etc and read the text file to get the results again

Comment: Isn't your loop code just going to overwrite the text file with an individual row on every iteration? Surely you need to open the file for output before the loop starts, then append each row onto the end of it, then close it at the end, or at least use the FILE_APPEND flag. I can't imagine searching a text file will be quicker than searching a properly-indexed database table, but you can experiment with that. Keep in mind fpc uses the actual server filesystem, not the virtual filesystem of your web site - if you want it in there, you'll have to add the path.

Comment: If you want to cache, use an actual cache system rather than a file. As above, disk I/O is unlikely to be faster than DB access, and it certainly won't be easier to search.

Comment: _How_ large is "large", actually? It doesn't look like that script you are using there does any filtering on the server side - the full set of records is loaded right away, and all the filtering is done purely on the client side. _"but I found out it takes a long time to do the search query"_ - I doubt it is actually the database query that takes so long; it is probably rather the time that the browser takes to render a _large_ table, which is known to be a slow process. And in regard to that, no server-side caching will help.

Comment: @CBroe I think you hit the nail on the head there. It loads all results (aprox 80.000) and then displays/filters it.

Comment: @Jacco Is it necessary to show all 80,000 rows at once?

Comment: You're probably better off with a solution that does the filtering on the server side (although you will have to write the code for _that_ part yourself then), for example DataTables with the server-side processing option - https://datatables.net/manual/server-side

Comment: The library you link requires sign up to see anything. But if it provides any server-side component, you are not using it.

Comment: Yes, I liked the filtered jquery display option of this method but did not realise the time impact for loading my page.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you for pointing me in that direction. Got it working just the way I want it now (might work on styling a bit later) [My database page](https://www.jaccoermers.nl/aviation/#airport-database)